# Python Bubble Chart Legands- TypeError

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Here's my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

%matplotlib inline

pandas.set_option ('max_columns',10)

df= pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Coding/Python/2.Python Data Analysis/Module 2- Python Data Visualization/M2-Bubble Chart with Labels and Legend data.csv')

plt.scatter(x=df['GDP per Capita'],y=df['Life Span'],s=df['Population']/1000, alpha=0.5, c=df['Bubble color'])
            #alpha at 0.5 to set the transparency 



#chart title, axis labels 
plt.title('GDP,Lifespan,Population (Bubble size)')
plt.xlabel(' GDP')
plt.ylabel('Lifespan')

#bubble labels 
x,y= df['GDP per Capita'],df['Life Span']
for i, txt in enumerate (df['Territory']):
    plt.annotate(txt,(x[i],y[i]))
    print(i,txt,x[i],y[i],df['Population'][i],df['Bubble color'][i])
#annotate: is used to assign the population with the chart sp have from text, the x and y will be the next one 
#it will print out the index number with the one that assigned with it as well 


#legend 
territory_list=list(df['Territory'])
bubble_color_list = list(df['Bubble color'])
l = []
for i in range (0,len(df.index)):
        l.append(mpatches.Patch(color=bubble_color_list[i],
                               alpha=0.5,
                               label=territory_list[i]))





plt.legend(handles=1,loc=(2,0))   
#the i is in the For loop is just basically like the one above to have all the information
```

I am looking to generate a Bubble chart with a legend for it but somehow it does not show the legend like it suppose to, just only the chart, and then show this message.

```
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which row is generating the error?

Comment: Hey @aprilangel, it is number 43 

---> 43 plt.legend(handles=1,loc=(2,0))

Comment: looks like handles will take iterables, at least you should put [1]. see docs here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `handles=1` in `plt.legend(handles=1,loc=(2,0))`.

`handles` must be a container, such as a list, tuple, etc...

Not only that, but a container of integers in unacceptable. Do not write `handles=[1, 2, 3]`

The following code shows how to properly call the `legend` method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some fake data.
a = b = np.arange(0, 3, .02)
c = np.exp(a)
d = c[::-1]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1 = ax.plot(a, c, 'k--')
line2 = ax.plot(a, d, 'k:')
line3 = ax.plot(a, c + d, 'k')

ax.legend((line1, line2, line3), ('line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'), loc=(2,0))

plt.show()
```